# Show Process which is observing the Clipboard

Tags: c#, windows

In order to figure out some bugs users reported I need some way to find out which process(es) are currently observing the clipboard. Is there any way to do that (or even an application which already does it)?

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward answer is to enumerate the "Global Hook Chain". However, that is a fairly tough procedure. As far as I can tell, no C# code exists to do it.

[retrieve the global hook chain in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746193/retrieve-the-global-hook-chain-in-windows)

It may be possible to troubleshoot this issue by listing all modules that are loaded in your application - by checking what DLLs have been injected, you may be able to get an idea of what installed applications are causing issues. This is readily possible in code or with a third party application. See [How do I list all loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies)

This answer from the above question offers some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3748945/1042744

Answer (score 0):

A Clipboard 'hook' might help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19858/Global-Windows-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

You asked if there's an existing application which does this. There is: David Candy's `GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip`, which I found via [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/145268/copy-paste-stops-working-on-windows-7).